# Как сделать корректный формат для номера телефона?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
const changeFormatToRussian = (num: string): string =>
    num.replace(/^[0-9]/, '+7').replace(/[^+\d]/g, '');
```

Моя фукнция форматирует номер, но после сивола + в начале можно вводить любое число.
Т.е. +3, +4, не заменяется на +7, а 2,3,4 заменяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
const phoneFormat = (s, plus = true) => {
  const startsWith = plus ? '+7' : '8';

  let phone = s.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  if (phone.startsWith('7') && plus) {
    phone = phone.substr(1);
  }
  if (phone.startsWith('8')) {
    phone = phone.substr(1);
  }

  return phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, `${startsWith} ($1) $2 $3 $4`);
};

 89992223355 -> +7 999 222 33 55
 @param {string} s номер телефона
 @param {boolean} [plus=true] формат +7 или 8
```

Comment: Если форматирование не нужно, просто return phone;